# ZEN CODING - Assign Id's with reference to parents id

Tags: html, emmet

```
table>tr#tr$*5>(td#td$_$*5)
```

gives me .........

```
   <table>
        <tr id="tr1">
            <td id="td1_1"></td>
            <td id="td2_2"></td>
            <td id="td3_3"></td>
            <td id="td4_4"></td>
            <td id="td5_5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr2">
            <td id="td1_1"></td>
            <td id="td2_2"></td>
            <td id="td3_3"></td>
            <td id="td4_4"></td>
            <td id="td5_5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr3">
            <td id="td1_1"></td>
            <td id="td2_2"></td>
            <td id="td3_3"></td>
            <td id="td4_4"></td>
            <td id="td5_5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr4">
            <td id="td1_1"></td>
            <td id="td2_2"></td>
            <td id="td3_3"></td>
            <td id="td4_4"></td>
            <td id="td5_5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr5">
            <td id="td1_1"></td>
            <td id="td2_2"></td>
            <td id="td3_3"></td>
            <td id="td4_4"></td>
            <td id="td5_5"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

But what i want is :

```
  <table>
        <tr id="tr1">
            <td id="td1_1"></td>
            <td id="td1_2"></td>
            <td id="td1_3"></td>
            <td id="td1_4"></td>
            <td id="td1_5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr2">
            <td id="td2_1"></td>
            <td id="td2_2"></td>
            <td id="td2_3"></td>
            <td id="td2_4"></td>
            <td id="td2_5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr3">
            <td id="td3_1"></td>
            <td id="td3_2"></td>
            <td id="td3_3"></td>
            <td id="td3_4"></td>
            <td id="td3_5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr4">
            <td id="td4_1"></td>
            <td id="td4_2"></td>
            <td id="td4_3"></td>
            <td id="td4_4"></td>
            <td id="td4_5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr5">
            <td id="td5_1"></td>
            <td id="td5_2"></td>
            <td id="td5_3"></td>
            <td id="td5_4"></td>
            <td id="td5_5"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Is there a way this can be done using Zen coding ?
Any help will be appreciated...
Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in dreamWeaver and notepad++

```
   table>tr#tr$*5>((td#td$_2)+(td#td$_3)+(td#td$_4)+(td#td$_5))
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will give you what you are looking for:

> ```
> table>tr#tr${td#td$_\$*5}*5
> ```

Comment: Ahan !! 
It gives me this :
<table>
     <tr id="tr1">td#td1_$*5</tr>
     <tr id="tr2">td#td2_$*5</tr>
     <tr id="tr3">td#td3_$*5</tr>
     <tr id="tr4">td#td4_$*5</tr>
     <tr id="tr5">td#td5_$*5</tr>
    </table>

Comment: Sorry, I have to double expand to make it work. That is I expand the outer most then highlight the remaining Zen and expand again. It is not perfect, but I use it a lot and have gotten quite fast at it.

Comment: i dint really get you...
can you paste the script ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 table>tr#tr$(td#td$_1)*5>(td#td$_2)+(td#td$_3)+(td#td$_4)+(td#td$_5)
```

The first part of code `table>tr#tr$*5` generate:

```
<table>
    <tr id="tr1"></tr>
    <tr id="tr2"></tr>
    <tr id="tr3"></tr>
    <tr id="tr4"></tr>
    <tr id="tr5"></tr>
</table>
```

And the second part `(td#td$_1)*5>(td#td$_2)+(td#td$_3)+(td#td$_4)+(td#td$_5)` generate:

```
<td id="td1_1"></td>
<td id="td1_2"></td>
<td id="td1_3"></td>
<td id="td1_4"></td>
<td id="td1_5"></td>
<td id="td2_1"></td>
<td id="td2_2"></td>
<td id="td2_3"></td>
<td id="td2_4"></td>
<td id="td2_5"></td>
<td id="td3_1"></td>
<td id="td3_2"></td>
<td id="td3_3"></td>
<td id="td3_4"></td>
<td id="td3_5"></td>
<td id="td4_1"></td>
<td id="td4_2"></td>
<td id="td4_3"></td>
<td id="td4_4"></td>
<td id="td4_5"></td>
<td id="td5_1"></td>
<td id="td5_2"></td>
<td id="td5_3"></td>
<td id="td5_4"></td>
<td id="td5_5"></td>
```

So combining the two last parts like this `table>tr#tr$(td#td$_1)*5>(td#td$_2)+(td#td$_3)+(td#td$_4)+(td#td$_5)` generate:

```
<table>
    <tr id="tr1">
        <td id="td1_1"></td>
        <td id="td1_2"></td>
        <td id="td1_3"></td>
        <td id="td1_4"></td>
        <td id="td1_5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2">
        <td id="td2_1"></td>
        <td id="td2_2"></td>
        <td id="td2_3"></td>
        <td id="td2_4"></td>
        <td id="td2_5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr3">
        <td id="td3_1"></td>
        <td id="td3_2"></td>
        <td id="td3_3"></td>
        <td id="td3_4"></td>
        <td id="td3_5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr4">
        <td id="td4_1"></td>
        <td id="td4_2"></td>
        <td id="td4_3"></td>
        <td id="td4_4"></td>
        <td id="td4_5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr5">
        <td id="td5_1"></td>
        <td id="td5_2"></td>
        <td id="td5_3"></td>
        <td id="td5_4"></td>
        <td id="td5_5"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This combination `table>tr#tr$(td#td$_1)*5>(td#td$_2)+(td#td$_3)+(td#td$_4)+(td#td$_5)` works for me in sublime text2.

Comment: I am using it doesn't work in dreamweaver.... I doubt it behaves differently in different editors!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in dreamweaver :

```
   table>tr#tr$*5>((td#td$_2)+(td#td$_3)+(td#td$_4)+(td#td$_5))
```